# Get systime from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I got a variable with a timestamp in `datetime` format:

`2022-02-10 11:37:43.253630`

And I want theequivalent value in `systime` (for unix)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the desired `systime` equivalent value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> dt.strptime('2022-02-10 11:37:43.253630','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 10, 11, 37, 43, 253630)
>>> x = dt.strptime('2022-02-10 11:37:43.253630','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> help(x.timestamp)
Help on built-in function timestamp:

timestamp(...) method of datetime.datetime instance
    Return POSIX timestamp as float.
>>> x.timestamp()
1644521863.25363
```